# React JS: jQuery is not working after React upgraded from version 16.13.1 to 18.2.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-dom, react-18

I'm upgrading the legacy code of a `React` app from version `16.13.1` to `18.2.0`.
The code currently utilizes `jQuery`. Before it's upgraded, the app works fine.

I found the issues in the `index.js` render.

React 16 uses this to render:

```js
import { render } from 'react-dom';

const container = document.getElementById('app');
render(<App tab="home" />, container);
```

While according to [react documentation](https://react.dev/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide), React 18 uses this:

```js
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';

const container = document.getElementById('app');
const root = createRoot(container);
root.render(<App tab="home" />);
```

I can revert the previous syntax and the `jQuery` will work, but then it will give me a warning:

```
Warning: ReactDOM.render is no longer supported in React 18. Use createRoot instead.
Until you switch to the new API, your app will behave as if it's running React 17.
```

What supposed to happen is, that when I click an expandable menu, e.g. Organization Unit, it will expand and show its children. The menu will collapse if clicked again.

When `jQuery` uses the first `render()` syntax, it works as intended:
[image: jQuery working]

When using `createRoot()`, nothing happened even when I clicked the menu repeatedly:
[image: jQuery not working]

Here is the `jQuery` code (legacy code, not mine), if needed:

```js
$("#sidebar-menu a").on("click", function (e) {
      if ($(this).parent().hasClass("submenu")) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
      if (!$(this).hasClass("subdrop")) {
        $("ul", $(this).parents("ul:first")).slideUp(350);
        $("a", $(this).parents("ul:first")).removeClass("subdrop");
        $(this).next("ul").slideDown(350);
        $(this).addClass("subdrop");
      } else if ($(this).hasClass("subdrop")) {
        $(this).removeClass("subdrop");
        $(this).next("ul").slideUp(350);
      }
    });

$("#sidebar-menu ul li.submenu a.active")
  .parents("li:last")
  .children("a:first")
  .addClass("active")
  .trigger("click")
```

Is there anything I missed?
Please let me know if additional information or context is needed.

Note:

- I know it's not the best practice to use `jQuery` in `React` due to both manipulating the DOM.
- Removing the `jQuery` is not an option.

Comment: You haven't explained what goes wrong when you use `createRoot()`

Comment: @Phil I added the gif

Comment: Please describe the problem using words. I can't tell what's supposed to happen, only you know that. Also, are there any errors reported in your dev-tools console for the non-working example?

Comment: Also, how and where are you including the `jquery.js` script in your app? What about the script in your question; where is that included?

Comment: You didn't answer the question about any errors in the console. Does anything show up that seems relevant, particularly when you're clicking on the menu?